# What is wrong with this formula that causes me to see the green triangles in the Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: c#, excel-formula, excel-interop, error-checking

I'm getting the green triangles in my Excel spreadsheet indicating that there is something wrong with the formula underlying that cell, although the data in that column's cells seems right and correctly formatted.

The code I'm using to populate that column is:

```
var avgWeeklyDeliveriesCell = (Excel.Range)_xlSheet.Cells[curDelPerfRow, 
    AVG_WEEKLY_DELIVERIES_COLUMN];
avgWeeklyDeliveriesCell.Value2 = string.Format("=ROUND(AVERAGE(C{0}:I{0}), 2)", 
    curDelPerfRow);
avgWeeklyDeliveriesCell.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00";
```

The values in that column are **3.43**, **1.57**, **2.00**, etc.

What is the problem with this formula ("=ROUND(AVERAGE(C{0}:I{0}), 2)")? It seems to work, so why are the green triangles making their presence visible?

### UPDATE

I added this code:

```
_xlApp.ErrorCheckingOptions.InconsistentFormula = false;
_xlApp.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = false;
```

...but it makes no difference; I still see the little green meanies.

### UPDATE 2

I know for approximately 99.97% certain that the warning is bogus (after all, the values are correct), yet I can't turn it off, as noted previously.

Why am I so sure my formula is good? Note this screamshot:

[image]

The msg that I see when I click the green triangle and hover over the sign with the green exclamation mark is, "The formula in this cell refers to a range that has additional numbers adjacent to it"

The formula displaying is "***=ROUND(AVERAGE(C10:I10), 2)***" which is what I want - an average of "Sun Orders" through "Sat Orders", but apparently due to there being another column ("Total Orders") situated between those computed and the one that complains greenly, it thinks something is amiss/haywire.

I'm thinking maybe I should change the formula to something like:

```
=ROUND(I11 / 7, 2)
```

...or:

```
=ROUND(I11 DIV 7, 2)
```

...but neither of those are accepted...

Comment: If you hoover over the green triangles, there should be kind of tool tip telling you, why Excel thinks there's an error. If you copy the formula manually into another cell - what happens? For sure you know, that you just can switch them off?

Comment: Yes, but the user doesn't want to switch them off - he just doesn't want to see them at all.

Comment: Thanks for that tip - I see, "The formula in this cell refers to a range that has additional numbers adjacent to it" And I was omitting a cell above that had data, so now that I have fixed that, those should go away...

Comment: You can switch of the background error checking totally... Did you find out the reason, why Excel thinks the formulas are bad?

Comment: But would this affect the user? After all, he has control over how his Excel is configured to behave, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure, that you might set this behaviour via Excel's API, but I'd have to figure this out myself... Anyway: If you know the reason, it is better to deliver correct data :-)

Comment: Yes, that's the preferred method! Nebenbei bemerkt, ist es kalt heute in Oesterreich? Hier in Monterey ist es ganz heiss (*zu* heiss, in der Tat).

Comment: 10°C in Februar? Ganz seltsam, oder? Aber immer noch ist es kalt in Wisconsin gewesen (was man fast "Neudeutschland" nennen koennte, wegen der vielen Deutschen dort).

Comment: In Ordnung, jetzt stehen sie ueber sieben tausend, ja?

Comment: I have experienced the same kind of issue, even tho there was nothing wrong with my formulas if I actually inserted them manually into excel by myself.. however, as soon as I used C# interop Value to assign the formula, excel showed all those triangles.. it's super weird, but I think you might have some luck trying out `Formula` cell property?

Comment: Auch mit ihnen! Erfreuen sich das warme Wetter!

Comment: @Peroxy: Have you got an example of using the Formula.Cell property?

Comment: `Range rng = activeWorksheet.get_Range("A1");`

`rng.FormulaArray = "=SUM(A4*C4,A5*C5,A6*C6,A7*C7)/SUM(A4:A7)";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the "Total Orders" column is a set value, not a formula. Set the "Total Orders" column to:

```
=SUM(C10:I10)
```

[image: Sample excel image showing the inserted value vs. formula]

Your warning will go away. Your average formula is correct, Excel is just looking out for you.

Comment: Thanks; I'll try it out tomorrow.

Comment: Yep, this did the trick:
totalOrdersCell.Value2 = string.Format("=SUM(C{0}:I{0})", curDelPerfRow);
Awedly enough, the dataset I receive that contains this data has a "TotalOrders" column, which I was using. Why there's a column for a value that can be calculated, I don't know.